# remove special/non-English characters from string in R

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning, stringr

I want to do some text mining analysis with my data collected from Facebook, but have some problems with the special/non-English characters in the text. The data looks like:

| doc_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 'ð˜ð—¶ð˜€ ð˜ð—µð—² ð˜€ð—²ð—®ð˜€ |
| 002 | I expect a return to normalcy...That is Bidenâ€™s great |
| 003 | 'Iâ€™m facing a prison sentence |

What I want is to remove the words containing these "strange" characters. I tried to do this by using

```
str_replace_all(text, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
```

But this doesn't work to my case. Any idea?

Comment: I realized these special characters are encoding issues (some of these are emotions). Set "encoding = UTF-8" works. But the question remains: how to remove the emotion pictures in text?

Comment: Do you want `str_replace_all(x, "[^A-z]", " ")`? It's unclear what your desired output is exactly. Your code shows `x` but what is `x` in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I want are just clean English texts.The "x" is the df$text

Answer (score 2):

A general answer to this kind of tasks is to specify the characters you want to keep. It appears that `:alnum:` comprises the greek letters and letters with accents.

Maybe this regex is more appropriate :

```
str_remove_all(x, "[^[\\da-zA-Z ]]")

[1] ""

[1] "I expect a return to normalcyThat is Bidens great"

[1] "Im facing a prison sentence"
```

I just replaced the alpha shortcut by `a-zA-Z`. I added a whitespace and used the `str_remove_all` function instead. Add any character you want to keep.